# Synchronization and unity of events time

Tags: special-relativity

It takes 8 minutes for sun light to reach the earth . In this case when we see the sun and feel the heat , that energy and heat was generated 8 minutes ago . Now imagine a spaceship is in the same distance from both the sun and the earth and so this light and inf that come from both are in the same time ,
Although the distance between the earth and the sun is 8 minutes , but from the spaceship's view everything happens at the same time .
How do you explain this issue?

Is it possible to find a point in entire space that has the most simultaneous to receive information among other phenomena ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. I think you're saying that the distance between the spaceship and the Sun equals the distance between the spaceship and the Earth. But what is "this issue" that you want explained? And your last paragraph simply doesn't make sense.

Comment: My issue is that an event in the sun will be seen 8 min later on earth but right moment and in the same time of another event on earth for the spaceship

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: last paragraph is about Generalize this idea to space and universe about finding a point(with constant or variable speed) in the space that has the most synchronized time with the other particles and systems of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

The events that are causally connected (such as the event of a light ray leaving the sun and the event of that light ray hitting a leaf on the earth) have the same chronological ordering among all inertial frame. So, for all observers (whether on the earth or on a spaceship between the sun and the earth), the light ray would first leave the sun and then hit the earth. The two events won't be simultaneously happening for any observer.

This is a crucial feature of the Lorentz transformations. It preserves the relative chronological order of causally connected events (more generally, it preserves the spacetime interval between two events).

Comment: but I think about sending or getting information from both sun and earth without reflecting light or anything else.

Comment: @AmirhosseinTaebi Can you explain a bit what you mean and how is it related to your question? As such, of course, you need some signal to travel from one place to another to get any information from one place to another.